# Fixing "Dirty bits not set" problem?

Tags: fat32, hotfix

How do I fix the "Dirty bits not set" error if I'm using a FAT32 system? I'm aware of the **fsutil** tool but apparently, it doesn't do it's job well on FAT32. Is there an alternative 3rd party software around? Can I fix it manually? Thanks a lot to those who'd answer!

Comment: Could you be more specific about the error message and the circumstances where you are getting it?

Comment: I'm getting the error whenever I try to load a game called Dead Frontier which runs absolutely fine on all other machines I've tested it in. Be it lesser in specs than the above unit or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best tool I'm aware of for analyzing and fixing low level problems in the dos/windows formats & environments is: http://www.grc.com/spinrite.htm

If it doesn't resolve the issue you probably have a hardware failure on your hands. I'd highly, highly recommend backing up anything/everything you can before you run any analysis/recovery software. In my experience with hardware failures they get worse and worse the more the disk runs, so you have a limited amount of time that the drive is on to get stuff off.. DO NOT write anything to the disk - read/backup stuff off it only. Then try spinrite to see if you can fix things that way. Sometimes it's just a bad sector that crops up and that doesn't compromise the whole disk..